# Matlab generating a matrix with similar elements

Tags: matlab

I have two matrices of size `100 x 1`

```
A=[a1;a2;a3;...;a100] 
N=[n1;n2;n3;...;n100]
```

I want to create a matrix of size `sum(N) x 1` that has `a1` elements of `n1`, `a2` elements of `n2` and ...:

[image]

How can I do this in MATLAB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`repelem`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html) to repeat each element in `A` by the corresponding entry in `N`

```
A = [1, 2, 3];
N = [3, 2, 1];

output = repelem(A, N);
%   1   1   1   2   2   3
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. but when I run this method, matlab send a " Undefined function or method 'repelem' for input arguments of type 'double'." error. despite of this method is there any other way?

Comment: @Paris What version of matlab?

Comment: See the duplicate I linked which offers alternatives to `repelem`

Comment: MATLAB version is R2011b. I see the duplicate page, I didn't  notice that and thank you very much for your offer, that is completely solving my problem.